# Eureka validate client before registering

Tags: spring-cloud, netflix-eureka, spring-cloud-netflix

I am considering an Eureka Server (service discovery) for my project...

I need the eureka server to validate the client metadata before registering it. Is it possible? Is there a callback in the server where I can implement it?

ps: i am not talking about spring security here.. What I need to do is implement a custom business logic.

Comment: Since it's a spring boot, you could implement a servlet filter that registers ahead of the eureka jersey filter.